# MockMvc result returns null for GET request in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, mockmvc

I have a problem with testing my Spring Boot Controller. I'm trying to test one of Controller put methods, but all I'm getting is Status expected:<200> but was:<400> error message.

**My Controller:**

```
@PutMapping(value = "/update", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateFields(@RequestBody List<UpdateModel> model) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(vaultService.updateFields(model), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**My ControllerTest:**
The URL is ok, and I have a list just like in the get method in my controller.

```
@Test
void updateFieldsTest() throws Exception {
    List<UpdateModel> response = new ArrayList<>();
    UpdateModel updateModel = new UpdateModel();
    response.add(updateModel);
    when(vaultService.updateFields(anyList()))
            .thenReturn(String.valueOf(response));

mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/api/update")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

**And here's an error message:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /api/update
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = hr.ogcs.ltt.api.lttapi.controller.LttController
           Method = hr.ogcs.ltt.api.lttapi.controller.LttController#updateFields(List)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
   at hr.ogcs.ltt.api.apicontroller.ControllerTest.updateFieldsTest(ControllerTest.java:113) <31 internal lines>
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)<9 internal lines>
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)<48 internal lines>
```

I guess it has to be something with sending the required parameter, but I'm not sure what exactly causes this 400 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've managed to find a solution, so here it is.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test updateFieldsTest")
void updateFieldsTest() throws Exception {
    List<UpdateModel> response = new ArrayList<>();
    UpdateModel updateModel = new UpdateModel();
    response.add(updateModel);
    when(vaultService.updateFields(anyList()))
            .thenReturn(String.valueOf(response));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response);

mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/api/update")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content(json)
        .accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

If you compare this code with the one in my original post, the difference is in adding the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Answering your own question is appreciated but you need to provide an explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have content in the request

```
mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/api/update")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content(jsonString)
        .accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added `.content("{[test, test1]}")` but the error is still the same.